# KDoc / Dokka: Ignore inherited methods in subclass

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-dokka, kdoc

I am generating documentation using KDoc/Dokka for an android library.

I have a custom view, which extends `LinearLayout`.

The problem is that `LinearLayout` contains hundreds of public methods. Dokka generates empty documentation for all of these methods, even though I did not use or override them in my own code.

This completely buries any of my own methods and makes the documentation near useless.

How can I prevent dokka from generating documentation for inherited methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this is not supported, probably we will add some flag to turn it on/off.

You can follow this issue: https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka/issues/1501

Answer (score 0):

From the answer by @andrzej-ratajczak the following can be used

```
pluginsMapConfiguration.set(
  ["org.jetbrains.dokka.base.DokkaBase": """{ "separateInheritedMembers": true}"""]
)
```

here an example of my own module

```
dokkaHtml {
    moduleName = "${project.name}"

    dokkaSourceSets {
        configureEach {
            // Suppress a package
            perPackageOption {
                // will match all packages and sub-packages
                matchingRegex.set(".*\\.internal.*")
                suppress.set(true)
            }

            // separate inherited members to avoid polluting our public API
            // https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka/issues/1501
            pluginsMapConfiguration.set(
                    ["org.jetbrains.dokka.base.DokkaBase": """{ "separateInheritedMembers": true}"""]
            )

        }
    }
}
```